# Echoing Questions from textfields, when a user has registrered sucsessfully

Tags: php, mysql, html

I want to give the users a message after they have registrered, that they have been sent a mail, with an activation link. After they have registrered without any errors. But i cant get their username and email displayed when i try to echo it with my text.

Heres my code:

```
    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'joined'){?>

    //I have som html code here but it doesnt have anything with the question to do so i deleted it.



     <?php


 $email =  $_GET['email'];
 $username =  $_GET['username'];
echo '<span style="color:#AFA;text-align:center;">Dear '.$username.' we have sent a mail to the email you registrered with :  '.$email.' please check both inbox and mail. To activate, click on the activation link in the mail. </span>'; $stmt = $db->prepare('select rank, memberid from members where memberid = ?');



    echo '<span style="color:#AFA;text-align:center;">Dear '.$username.' we have sent a mail to the email you registrered with :  '.$email.' please check both inbox and trash for the mail. To activate, click on the activation link in the mail. </span>';   $stmt = $db->prepare('select rank, memberid from members where memberid = ?');

        $stmt = $db->prepare('select rank, memberid from members where memberid = ?');
    $stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['memberID']));





     ?>
```

So, the text displays, but not the username and the email.

Comment: You check to see if $_GET is set, then you grab data from $_POST. Is this what you intended? Post var_dump($_GET); and  var_dump($_POST);

Answer (score 0):

You are testing GET but using POST

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'joined'){?>
```

.

```
$email =  $_POST['email'];
$username =  $_POST['username'];
```

try using GET too in assignment

```
      $email =  $_GET['email'];
   $username =  $_GET['username'];
```

Comment: I just updated my question, still no luck:( Any ideas?

Comment: check the content of $_GET and $_POST  using var_dump($_GET) and var_dump($_POST) and eval the real content..

Comment: this is what i get.. array(1) { ["action"]=> string(6) "joined" }  and array(1) { ["action"]=> string(6) "joined" }  Whats it saying? And why doesnt it display the username and email?

Comment: this mean that  you don't pass  any value for  username and email using GET format (url formatte ?username=your_name&email=your_email@example.com.. so you should check for the code that you use for the request ....but i think this is another question .

Answer (score 0):

Well the simple answer is you are referencing the input as $_GET and then showing the data in a $_POST.  That 'may' work but is not recommended.  Look at your `method` in the form statement, and either use $_GET or $_POST for the whole thing.